# How much power to keep surface of aluminum plate at given temperature?

Tags: temperature, power

I want to heat one side of an aluminum plate enough to hold the other side of that plate $100K$ above ambient.  I'm willing to assume that the heated side of the plate is "well" insulated (along with the edges, if it's significant).  The plate is $500cm^2$ and is open to air in a normal room.

I think the formula is simple enough:  $P = \frac{\Delta T}{R_{pa}}$ Where $R_{pa}$ is the thermal resistance of the plate to air in $\frac{K}{W}$.  The problem I'm having finding the thermal resistance is that most heat-sink-like applications would care about the *bottom* of the plate in this case:  the goal would be to *cool* the *bottom* of the plate.  I don't actually care what the temperature of the bottom is (within reason):  I want to hold the top at a specific temperature.

If I attack it from first principles and consider that the the thermal resistance of aluminum is irrelevant (since it's the top surface I care about) then all I need is the thermal resistance of the air above it.  The guessing part comes in when trying to figure out how thick a slab of air to consider.  If I guesstimate 3cm I get:

$$T_{air} = 0.025 \frac{W}{mK}$$

$$T = \frac{0.05m^2}{0.03m}T_{air} = 0.04 \frac{W}{K}$$

$$R_{pa} = \frac{1}{T}$$

$$P = \frac{100K}{R_{pa}} = 100K \cdot 0.04 \frac{W}{K} = 4W$$

The 4W result feels about an order of magnitude too low.  Of course if I change my guess of the air thickness to consider to 3mm I get 40W which seems more reasonable.  But instead of calculating the wattage I need I'm just guessing in different units.

Comment: Convection? Radiation?